# What are the required layers/ configurations for a minimalist Yocto project

Tags: linux, yocto, bsp

I am using yocto to build the necessary images to boot my target (Renesas V3H). After cloning poky I cloned also the [Renesas BSP layer](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-renesas/). then I started the configuration:

```
source oe-init-build-env build
bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-renesas
```

Then my `build/conf/bblayers.conf` looks like this :

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
/home/user/Workspace/poky/meta \
/home/user/Workspace/poky/meta-poky \
/home/user/Workspace/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
/home/user/Workspace/poky/meta-renesas \
"
```

My questions are:

- What are the required layers that should be built, I think for example meta-yocto-bsp is not required am I correct ?
- What is the value to be given to the variable `MACHINE` can anyone give a hint how to search it ?

Answer (score 1):

If it is your own board, you will need your own layer with at least the MACHINE definition.
If you are using an eval board from Renesas, you might find a suitable machine in the meta-renesas layer.

meta-yocto-bsp is sample BSPs for Beaglebone and other off the shelf boards, so you won't need it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, my basic understanding is that the variable `MACHINE` take one of the file names under `meta-xxx/conf/machine`, example under `meta-yocto-bsp` there are `beaglebone-yocto.conf  edgerouter.conf  genericx86-64.conf  genericx86.conf` so `MACHINE` can take one of the values `beaglebone-yocto, edgerouter`, ... However under  `meta-renesas/conf/machine` I can only find the `include` folder so how to set `MACHINE` in this case

Comment: I guess in that case, the meta-renesas layer is only building blocks for defining your own layer for your project, and not coming with a complete example project definition itself.  You'll have to use those includes to make your own machine definition.